# How does Social Security work in the United States?

Tags: united-states, social-security

There are political discussions in the United States regarding whether Social Security is maintainable over time.

I want to know how the Social Security system works in United States, and what the basis is of the concerns about its maintainability.

Comment: This question seems too broad, and not necessarily (just) political.  Maybe narrow it down to an aspect that can be answered reasonably in one question?

Comment: @BrockAdams The politics influence several aspects like education, economy, etc... Saying that this question is not about politics is being a bit blind.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto - It's more that there are plenty of non-political aspects to it. Frankly, I don't think it's too broad, but it does seem to be likely to be fully answered on Wikipedia. I won't VTC but am tempted.

Comment: @BrockAdams - please have a look at both the answer provided and my edit. Hopefully you will judge it as reopenable

Comment: @DVK, Okay, it's reopened.

Comment: "How does the Social Security Work in United States?" A: It doesn't! (cue rim shot) I'm here all night, please tip your wait staff!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First, the formal basic information on how Social Security works**:

Informally, it's very simple from the view of an individual:

- A portion of your income is mandatorily taxes (FICA tax), with the proceeds used to fund the Social Security fund.
- Once a person reaches eligibility to be paid Social Security (usually specific age), they receive payments from that fund.
- The system was designed and tuned so that, on average, given how many people work, how much they make, how long they are expected to live after they retire, and how much the population grows, on average, more money is expected to be collected in FICA taxes than expected to be paid out to retirees.

---

**Here's a bit more on how Social Security formally works** - this seems to be fairly comprehensively answered on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_%28United_States%29), especially [Current Operation section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_%28United_States%29#Current_operation)

> In the United States, Social Security refers to the Old-Age, Survivors, and Disability Insurance (OASDI) federal program.

**Financing:**

> Social Security is primarily funded through dedicated payroll taxes called Federal Insurance Contributions Act tax (FICA). ...
>
> The FICA taxes are imposed on all workers and self-employed persons. Employers are required to report wages for covered employment to Social Security ...employers deduct these payroll taxes from workers' wages before they are paid. Generally, the payroll tax is imposed on everyone in employment earning "wages" ... and also taxes net earnings from self-employment.

**Trust fund:**

> Social Security taxes are paid into the Social Security Trust Fund maintained by the U.S. Treasury...
>
> **Current year expenses are paid from current Social Security tax revenues**. [ *This is critical to understanding the problem - DVK*]
>
> When revenues exceed expenditures, as they did between 1983 and 2009, the excess is invested in special series, non-marketable U.S. Government bonds, thus the Social Security Trust Fund indirectly finances the federal government's general purpose deficit spending.
>
> **The Social Security Administration's authority to make benefit payments as granted by Congress extends only to its current revenues and existing Trust Fund balance**, i.e., redemption of its holdings of Treasury securities. Therefore, Social Security's ability to make full payments once annual benefits exceed revenues depends in part on the federal government's ability to make good on the bonds that it has issued to the Social Security trust funds. As with any other federal obligation, the federal government's ability to repay Social Security is based on its power to tax and borrow and the commitment of Congress to meet its obligations.

---

**Now, for the maintainability problem.**

The short short version:

- Social Security is a closed system. E.g., it can not pay out benefits above the money that it owns. Its ONLY revenue source is FICA taxes (as far as accounting, the bonds purchased for surplus collection are also considered revenue, but in reality they are simply prior years' unspent FICA taxes).
- As noted at the very beginning, the FICA taxes and benefit eligibility was designed with **very specific demographic and economic assumptions, to make the system sustainable**.
- Currently 2 of the main assumptions no longer hold true:

  1. the # of years that benefits are paid out per person increased dramatically due to average life span increase in USA
  2. the amount of the workforce compared to amount of people in retirement is starting to drop precipitously due to Baby Boomer generation unwisely having chosen to have significantly fewer children than SS models anticipated).

**So, once we have "too many" Baby Boomers retired and drawing SS benefits, for "too many" years, with "too few" - relative to that - people paying FICA taxes - there eventually simply won't be enough money in the system to pay all of the promised benefits, without additional sources of revenue.**  (where "too" refers to assumptions made when original SS system was calibrated)

---

Somewhat controversially, Social Security can be envisioned as a giant Ponzi scheme (marketing pyramid). Here's how it works.

- Let's assume, for ease of modeling, that a human being lives for 3 years:

  - 1 year childhood
  - 1 year working adulthood (Children are born when you turn 1 year old)
  - 1 year retirement.
- We start with a population of 4 people called generation #1 (aka G#1) - split into married couples, aged 1 (they can start work), another 4 people called Generation #0, aged 2 (retired), and an empty fund.
- Everyone working earns $100 a year, pays 50% FICA tax. Every retiree gets $50 Social Security a year. The math works out the same as real life, just easier to calculate.

  <sub>We use 50% because in real life, a lot more people are working than getting SS due to the difference between retirement longevity vs. work longevity.</sub>
- Here's what happens:

  - **Year 0**.

    SSTF balance = $0
  - **Year 1.**

    4 people from G#1 work for a year.

    They pay $100 * 4 * 50% = $200

    They give birth to 2 children per couple (4 total) of G#2.

    4 retired people get their SS checks for $50 each, for $200 total.

    End of year SS Trust Fund balance: $0 + $200 - $200 = $0.

    Now, here's the interesting part to show the actual mechanics. *Each bill we collected in taxes into  the trust fund has a post-it not attached, with the year it was collected*.

    Notice that G#1 people got their SS paid by bills collected from G#0.
  - **Year 2.**

    4 people from G#2 work for a year.

    They pay $100 * 4 * 50% = $200

    They give birth to 3 children per couple (6 total) of G#3. Yay for Baby Boomers!

    4 retired people from G#1 get their SS checks for $50 each, for $200 total.

    End of year SS Trust Fund balance: $0 + $200 - $200 = $0.

    Notice that G#1 people got their SS paid by bills collected from G#2!

    This is super-important! People in G#1, when they retire, are NOT paid by the money they paid into the system as a FICA! They are paid out of the money **that the next generation pays right now, while they are retired!**.

    Also note how everything is in perfect balance. Our 50% FICA tax was designed so that we have as much money coming in as paying out.

    Now, let's see what happens when you start modeling population changes...
  - **Year 3.**

    6 people from G#3 work for a year.

    They pay $100 * 6 * 50% = $300

    But the Baby Boomers like their creature comfort, and 2 of the couples only have 1 child each. G#4 has 4 people.

    4 retired people from G#2 get their SS checks for $50 each, for $200 total.

    End of year SS Trust Fund balance: $0 + $300 - $200 = $100. We are in surplus!

    Notice that G#2 people got their SS paid by bills collected from G#3! And since G#2 had  more kids than 2, the SS fund now has extra money.
  - **Year 4.**

    4 people from G#4 work for a year.

    They pay $100 * 4 * 50% = $200

    They give birth to 1 child per couple (2 total) of G#5 .

    6 retired people from G#3 get their SS checks for $50 each, for $300 total.

    End of year SS Trust Fund balance: $100 + $200 - $300 = $0. We ATE the surplus!

    Notice that G#3 people got their SS paid by bills collected from G#4! And since G#3 had  LESS kids than 2, the SS fund's extra money was spent right out.
  - **Year 5.**

    2 people from G#5 work for a year.

    They pay $100 * 2 * 50% = $100

    They give birth to 2 children per couple (2 total) of G#6.

    4 retired people from G#4 get their SS checks for $50 each, for $200 total.

    End of year SS Trust Fund balance: $0 + $100 - $200 = -$100.

    **WE JUST RAN OUT OF MONEY,
    because the next level of Ponzi pyramid did not have enough people.**

Your Social Security just went broke. Welcome to what will happen to 21st Century in USA, when all the Boomers who couldn't be bothered to raise enough children will all over the sudden retire, and live longer than SS-originally-planned in retirement years.

Comment: "Social Security fund" is an accounting fiction however. In fact, Social Security payments come to US Treasury, and Social Security payments come out of US Treasury. There's no some huge vault where Social Security funds are stored, to be paid later to the recipients - in fact, those funds are immediately converted to US government bonds, which means they are effectively spent by the government immediately after collecting, with the promise to pay later when the time comes.

Comment: This however also means Social Security can not really "go broke" - as the government can always raise taxes and/or modify benefits to fill up the missing parts. Since the "fund" is a fiction, backed by the full revenue stream of the US govt, unless the US govt goes broke Social Security doesn't, because they are effectively the same.

Comment: @StasM - by law, Social Security can not pay out more than they have in this "fictional" Fund account. As stated in the answer, quoted from Wiki from actual law: **The Social Security Administration's authority to make benefit payments as granted by Congress extends only to its current revenues and existing Trust Fund balance**

Comment: ...And yes, one reason why Right Wingers are so in favor of entitlement reform is precisely their fear that, once SSA runs out of money, they will start stealing from the rest of Federal Budget, because that quoted law can easily be amended; and Boomers are the largest voting block of all.

Comment: @DVK laws can be changed, and there's no doubt they will be, once the deficiency of the fund will be imminent. Look at what happens with "debt ceiling".

Comment: @StasM - What happens with debt ceiling is the same thing that happens with typical alcoholic... "lemme borrow ANOTHER $5 for the VERY EVER LAST drink EVER"

Comment: Another factor worth adding to this excellent answer is that politically it is very dangerous to tweak the system to raise the retirement age where benefits can be collected or to reduce the payouts. For that matter, even not raising the benefits by enough every year can be very unpopular. Also, it is well known that old people tend to be reliable voters so any politician trying the balance the system by shifting resources from today's retiree's to tomorrow's might have trouble getting re-elected.

Comment: @DVK: I've heard this pyramid discussion a lot, and I think it is fundamentally flawed for the industrialized world. I wrote my thoughts as another answer, as they were too long for a comment. But please feel free to comment.

Comment: I don't understand how an answer that claims it's a Ponzi scheme is the one selected. It's an interesting claim, but simple punditry, not non-partisan analysis.

Comment: @DA. - you are welcome to explain how it's NOT Ponzi scheme. `A Ponzi scheme is a fraudulent investment operation that pays returns to its investors from their own money **or the money paid by subsequent investors, rather than from profit earned by the individual or organization running the operation**. ` You saying "it is partisan to call it so" doesn't make it not one. The rate of growth of the pyramid is slower, but the mechanics is 100% identical. You get paid out of the money brought in by the people you recruited (next generation).

Comment: No, it does make it so. To choose to compare SS to a criminal endeavor is a conscious choice, just as comparing it to a grass roots community fund raiser would be conscious choice. Both could be argued valid comparisons on some levels, but they are both partisan choices.

Comment: @DA. - the only difference between lottery and illegal gambling is that one is run by the government. If you don't understand how the underlying finance of SS works, you shouldn't argue over it. The fact that government decided that SS is legal does NOT change the fact that it is run using EXACTLY 100% same rules as a ponzi scheme. Either explain how the financial details of SS is different from Ponzi, or quit your baseless argument.

Comment: @dvk "the only difference between lottery and illegal gambling is that"...one helps pay for schools and wildlife protection and the other helps bust knee caps and enriches Italian mafia families! See how easy that is!? I *love* partisan analogies. It's what makes debating politics *fun*--a sport. Punditry is a fine art, IMHO. But with all that said, I was under the impression that the goal of SE was to try and remain non partisan (which, admittedly, might make for a very boring politics site...)

Comment: @DA. - So, by your argument, if I run a casino and use the profits to run a school, you will fully agree that I'm running a legitimate legal business that is NOT gambling?

Comment: @dvk *that* is the kind of debate I love! But again, I think that's defeating the entire goal of this experiment. We're not supposed to be using partisan analogies in the first place as it's debate fodder.

Comment: @DA. - my answer was pure math. You're the one who came in and started playing word games in comments without a shred of evidence.

Comment: @DVK "my answer was pure math." Pure math would have been...well, just math. You added the 'ponzi scheme' label. As I said, I *do love* partisan spin, but I thought on SE if it were to be used, it would at least be done with a wink and a smile. Alas, I'm seeing a lot of it being done by posters that seemingly are convinced that they are 100% correct. I'm always a little suspect of anyone that claims they are 100% correct when it comes to politics. ;)

Comment: A ponzi scheme is generally marketed as some sort of investment fund where investors hope to get more money out than they put in.  Social security, on the other hand, is designed to be a 0-sum game on average.  It was designed such that if population was consistent(neither growing nor  shrinking) to sustain itself.  It's more comparable to insurance

Comment: I guess a more neutral term for the way the social insurance works would be pay-as-you-go financing. However, if [understood correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_insurance), the US social insurance differs from others by the fact that it actually can go bankrupt because there are guaranteed payments. Usually pay-as-you-go social insurance cannot go bancrupt as it operates on a total paid in = total paid out basis (e.g. in Germany you accumulate "contribution points" and the current value of the contribution point is calculated each year anew).

Comment: ... This is not fraudulent, but was meant to be like that by design. However, statuary pension casses are a very political topic, so the system is subject to all kinds of political changes and adjustments (e.g. in Germany cross-financing by taxes, raising the pension age) and "populistic frauds" (a famous one: "die Rente ist sicher" = "pensions are guaranteed" - which in a way is true, but there is no builtin guarantee about the value of the contribution point, and there never has been...)

Comment: I highly recommend reading [social insurance trustee report](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/trsum/index.html) and [this newspaper article](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/feb/13/social-security-reserves-forecast-to-run-dry-in-20/?page=all). So there's still 10 or 20 a to steer against the bancrupcy before it happens. However, I got the impression that [quite some adjustments have been made in the past already](http://www.ssa.gov/history/1983amend.html) and I guess that there have been social insurance crises in the US before.  @DVK: could you clarify this?

Comment: @cbeleites - the line that I found the most critical was "After 2020, Treasury will redeem trust fund assets in amounts that exceed interest earnings until exhaustion of trust fund reserves in 2033, **three years earlier than projected last year**". For some strange reason, I have very little confidence in the current year's projections either, based on their track record :)

Comment: @cbeleites - either way, they admit that they won't be able to make payments 20 years from now if the mechanics isn't changed (e.g. raise the start age, means test, decrease benefits or increase the tax). Whether the date is today or 20 years from now is immaterial.

Comment: As far as being fraudulent or not, technically speaking it may or may not be faudulent if there are representations that the future payments are **guaranteed** (because they are not guaranteed, under current legislation). The definition of fraud is promising someone benefits that are known to not be deliverable in exchange for payments.

Comment: I don't see why the "important" point of people being paid by later generations is important. It's "social" security, not "personal" security. Society pays = whoever produces goods and provides services provides some of them to the elderly. About "couldn't be bothered" - population increases are not sustainable indenfinitely anyway, one needs to start planning for a steady state size-wise and an ageing population eventually. In a US-like money-based economy, it's mostly a case of tweaking the tax rate - either through FICA or other forms of taxation - to maintain the SocSec benefits.

Answer (score 1):

(These are rather additional thoughts to [@DVK's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/184/1584) which are too long for a comment.)
Also, it is from a German perspective, because I know the numbers here better. There quite some differences between the US and Germany, but I think they don't matter that much for this question.

---

**edit:** turns out that the US system is more different from the German system than I initially thought from @DVK's answer, because
in Germany the pay-as-you-go is set up in a way that it ultimately will never go bancrupt, but the contributions may explode or the paid out pensions may loose in value instead (or, cross-financing by general taxes, which is roughly 1/3 of the total volume already, increases).
In contrast, the US system is more closed, and if I understood correctly, guarantees a money value of payments, but OTOH does hold reserves and projects the sustainability of the funding for 75 years.

However, knowing this, I think that the scenarios I calculate below actually are *more relevant* to the original question than I thought: because the US social security actually does these projections, *they should have been pointing out the problem early*. A decline in births is something that can be spotted basically immediately. The decline in births could have been spotted [latest by ca. 1965](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers), probably earlier because it was linked to a [solid reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_oral_contraceptive_pill).
In 1965 the *oldest* of the baby boomers were 20 years old - that would have left almost 50 years to accumulate more reserves, and the *whole work life* for most of the baby boomers. Obviously, the decision whether to increase FICA or reduce paid out pensions is a political one.

But in any case, this population pyramid of the USA does not suggest any serious decline in the working generation:

[image: US population pyramid]

particularly not compared to other countries:

[image: Germany population pyramid]

Due these social security reserve projections say that at the current funding scheme, the pension cass will run out of money within [10](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/feb/13/social-security-reserves-forecast-to-run-dry-in-20/?page=all) or [20](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/trsum/index.html) years - still quite some time to take decisions.
So from a German perspective, I'd say with respect to the demographic change, the US system works quite well.

---

So:
The calculation seems somewhat arbitrary to me (as does the major part of similar discussions I've heard): it assumes that children are raised at no cost.

In fact the 1 yr working adulthood has to pay for the pensions as well as for the children. A quick search on some numbers for Germany

- average pension (≈ 800 €/month) * 18,5 yrs average duration of pension payment ≈ 175.000 €.
- Raising a child to the age of 18 is quoted with ≈120.000€. But lots of people do not start into the working adulthood at age of 18 nowadays.
  This doesn't include the costs for education (paid by taxes which are of course paid by the working adults. My guess is that kindergarden + school + university is at the very least another 120.000€/person).

Bottomline: order of magnitude for raising a child and providing good education is at least the same as for the pension. With that the calculation changes:

- first change we observe: Paying as much pension as is leftover for the working doesn't leave any money either for the adults or for the children. We'll have to lower the pension niveau to 1/3 of gross wage (or, stay with 50%, but live 4 years and work 2 of them). However, I'll pay them 300 €/a, and call it gross product.

```
yr children adults                 retired     
    require require  family gross   require pension private comment
                    savings product         cass    savings
1   4=400€   4=400€     ±0€   1200€  4=400€     ±0€     ±0€
2   6=600€   4=400€   -200€   1200€  4=400€     ±0€     ±0€ uups 
3   4=400€   6=600€     ±0€   1800€  4=400€   +200€     ±0€ debts payed off
4   2=200€   4=400€   +200€   1200€  6=600€     ±0€     ±0€
5   2=200€   2=200€     ±0€    600€  4=400€     ±0€     ±0€ fortunately there were savings
6   2=200€   2=200€     ±0€    600€  2=200€     ±0€     ±0€
```

Note that the paying off of the debts does not include any interest, and that bancrupcy of the pension is only avoided by the retirements savings of the large (6p.) generation who had to pay off the debts their parents made for raising them **and** had to accumulate savings for their own retirement. This was possible because they did have the economic strength, but had they not saved the surplus while working, the pension system would have been bankrupt.

A more "German" version would not have family savings, but a governmental education cass in addition to the pension cass, and cross-funding would happen between pension and education.

Here's a variant II, where the parents economize to raise their children.

```
yr children adults                 retired     
    require require  family gross   require pension private comment
                    savings product         cass    savings
1   4=400€   4=400€     ±0€   1200€  4=400€     ±0€     ±0€
2   6=500€   4=300€     ±0€   1200€  4=400€     ±0€     ±0€ families shorten expenses by 200€
3   4=400€   6=600€   +200€   1800€  4=400€   +200€     ±0€ 
4   2=200€   4=400€   +200€   1200€  6=600€     ±0€   +200€ adults inherit 200€
5   2=200€   2=200€     ±0€    600€  4=400€     ±0€   +200€ still something left to inherit
6   2=200€   2=200€     ±0€    600€  2=200€     ±0€   +200€ and that stays like this
```

The situation would be basically the same if the grandparents help saving the initial 200€. The "wealth" of 200 € that is left at the end was basically created by the savings of the 2nd year. Note that the pension cass is barely left with a ±0.

The bottomline is that with this system, a **growth** in total population is the problem unless the gross product increases accordingly. Note that the estimated costs for education mean that this problem is even bigger, because each child costs roughly 1 1/2 as much as a retired person (people also live of their savings in retirement, but in any case raising a child is nowhere near negligible compared to pension costs). Yet, often more children are seen as the solution to the retirement problem. That would work only if raising a child was cheap, i.e. cutting down education - not a good idea.
A **decrease** in population can in principle be buffered by a partially capital/savings based pension system, but that needs economic discipline (of which I do not see much in current politics - *edit: yet the US social security reserves seem to me amazingly well preserved*). I've often heard the argument that a capital-based retirement system doesn't work out as the retired needs someone to look after him and someone to grow the food when he is retired. Howevder, also that is only partially true: there could be more people to grow the food if they didn't need to build a house to live in because the retired had done that already. But note also, that in our scenario with a population growth first before the decrease in population, the capital based system would have been bancrupt immediately: during population growth, there was no possibilty to save for the retirement.

In reality, I guess one also needs to take into account that saved money "itches", and "wants" to get spent (maybe that's more a European problem - see edit above). Particularly if it isn't one's own savings, e.g. politicians deciding at the +200€ stage of the pension cass to cut the tax rate going into pensions. Or, the baby boomers in the first scenario may find it unfair that they should save after they have already paid the debts. So they spend the surplus, and then the system goes bancrupt.

Comment: The original question ONLY discussed a **closed system** (social security) - the amount of money in that system is 100% independent of whether it takes $0 to raise a child, or $100,000. Therefore, your answer - while possibly correct from the point of view of overall economy (it's too involved to render snap  judgement either way) does NOT really address the issue of whether Social Security is solvent or not...

Comment: ... People would have paid amount X into social security no matter how many kids they raise and how much they pay for them - and would get PAID by social security 100% independently of whether they saved $500,000 for retirement by NOT spending on children they didn't birth. Therefore, such childless people draw the same from Social Security system, BUT (by proxy of their never-born-kids not paying into it) contribute less on the net.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to downvote this answer, since it doesn't address the actual question (see comments above), but with the caveat that this is a VERY well thought out answer, and at first glance correct one - **just to a different question**. ("how does birthrate affect net economic growth" would probably a good question for this answer).

Comment: @DVK: wrt closed system: so you really have a closed system? Then we found a first important difference: in Germany the statutory pension insurance "claims" to be paid by the respective payroll deductions (called pension cass contributions, not termed a tax) - but in fact about 1/3 of the money comes from governmental sources (i.e. other taxes), so it is far from a closed system.

Comment: @DVK: for generation 0 it is accepted that instead of paying money into the system, they provided generation 1. My scenarios also do the reverse: a generation can pay more (savings) instead of raising children. In Germany, this is actually done in some aspects (there are parts of social insurance where you have higher fees as long as you are without children, you will also receive pension for years without contribution because of raising children as if you had paid contributions, most of the education cost is tax financed, you get a payback for raising children, ...).

Comment: @DVK: As for being an answer to another question - that I'm aware of, and that's why the very first sentence says it is in fact a long comment to your answer. I decided to write it down here as I've met the scenario you describe in many discussions, and with the exception of one single newspaper article, children always were discussed as the future payers, but the discussion never included the fact that both children and old people actually need to be cared and provided for - which I believe is a rather basic fact about life.

Comment: @DVK: Maybe the right question would be asked by me: *Why does the "demographics" discussion get along without ever thinking of the investment you have to / want to put into children?*"

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer the entire question, as it appears a lot has already been written, but will try and provide a really quick TL/DR response to your second part:

> and what the basis is of the concerns about its maintainability

The concern is that Social Security benefits are paid by the current working generation, and benefits are taken by the current retired generation.

This creates two potential problems (both of which are happening now):

1. If more people are retired than working, more money comes out than goes in and
2. If people live longer, more people take more money out for a longer amount of time than originally planned.

Alas, the system wasn't designed to handle these fluctuating variables automatically very well...hence the need to debate how we're going to go forward with fixes.

The SUPER-SHORT-TL/DR VERSION:

Social Security wasn't set up to handle the fluctuations of the economy and demographics as well is it maybe could have been.

Comment: "If more people are retired than working, more money comes out than goes in" **This isn't correct**, you need about [3 workers for every retiree](http://mercatus.org/publication/how-many-workers-support-one-social-security-retiree)

Comment: @user1873 huh? How does that link disagree with the statement of mine you are quoting?

Comment: @user1873 if your link was meant to imply that things "aren't quite that simple" I'd agree, so added an even shorter summation that hopefully accommodates the massive amount of variables a bit more broadly.

Comment: The contrapositive isn't true. If you say P => Q, then !Q => !P (ie P="more retiree than worker", Q="more money out than in" so, "More money in than out or net zero" => "more workers than retiree or same number") So, you see the problem is that equal numbers of retiree/workers results in more money going out.

Comment: @user1873 Yes, you are technically correct. Though, if I were to sling the term contrapositive around (admittedly, it's not a term I use with any regularity), I might state: the contrapositive of my statement isn't *necessarily* true--specifically when there is is less that 2x the number of worker to retired people at this particular moment (ie, the current set of demographics and economic conditions we're dealing with). Hopefully my addendum is a better catch-all in the TL/DR vein.

Comment: I didn't DV, but was itching to since IMHO, the answer doesn't really contain anything that wasn't already covered by mine. I know you got hung up on hating SS being compared to Ponzi, but half the answer before was exactly explaining the same thing that your answer did.

Comment: @DVK yep. it does. Just a shorter version. If you feel it should be downvoted because of that, go for it.

Comment: How can it be a concern that the current working generation pays while the current retiree generation benefits? That's the whole point of the system. The concern you describe is the imbalance between the sizes of those groups on one hand, and the payments-to-benefits ratios on the other hand.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, that is the concern I described. I think we're in agreement.